# OpenCL, Understanding VectorAdd program

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCL, with very limited background in C/C++.
I've been given this OpenCL program that adds two vectors, and supposed to figure out how it works. It comes from Intel:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/opencl/vector-addition.html

Would it be correct to say: each kernel uses 1 element from A and 1 element from B to calculate 1 element of Z?

To me, it looks like it determines the number of devices (num_devices), and essentially divides the problem size (N) by num_devices, to determine the number of elements per device (n_per_device[]). Then it creates arrays of random numbers for each device (input_a[] and input_b[]) with n_per_device number of elements.

Then these arrays are used by the kernel, where addition of the whole array is performed and stored as Z.

For example, say if the number of devices available is 1000, and problem size (N) is 1,000,000; the n_per_device is 1000 (and since there is no remainder it is the same for all), and it would generate 1000 arrays of input_a and input_b, with 1000 elements in each. Then a respective pair of arrays of 1000 elements are taken by the kernel and added together - in other words each execution of the kernel adds 1000 elements?

Am I following anything, or totally wrong here?

The kernel is:

```
 // ACL kernel for adding two input vectors
__kernel void vectorAdd(__global const float *x, 
                        __global const float *y, 
                        __global float *restrict z)
{
    // get index of the work item
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    // add the vector elements
    z[index] = x[index] + y[index];
}
```

The host (main) code is (sorry it is long, not sure what's not important):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This host program executes a vector addition kernel to perform:
//  C = A + B
// where A, B and C are vectors with N elements.
//
// This host program supports partitioning the problem across multiple OpenCL
// devices if available. If there are M available devices, the problem is
// divided so that each device operates on N/M points. The host program
// assumes that all devices are of the same type (that is, the same binary can
// be used), but the code can be generalized to support different device types
// easily.
//
// Verification is performed against the same computation on the host CPU.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "CL/opencl.h"
#include "AOCL_Utils.h"

using namespace aocl_utils;

// OpenCL runtime configuration
cl_platform_id platform = NULL;
unsigned num_devices = 0;
scoped_array<cl_device_id> device; // num_devices elements
cl_context context = NULL;
scoped_array<cl_command_queue> queue; // num_devices elements
cl_program program = NULL;
scoped_array<cl_kernel> kernel; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<cl_mem> input_a_buf; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<cl_mem> input_b_buf; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<cl_mem> output_buf; // num_devices elements

// Problem data.
const unsigned N = 1000000; // problem size
scoped_array<scoped_aligned_ptr<float> > input_a, input_b; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<scoped_aligned_ptr<float> > output; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<scoped_array<float> > ref_output; // num_devices elements
scoped_array<unsigned> n_per_device; // num_devices elements

// Function prototypes
float rand_float();
bool init_opencl();
void init_problem();
void run();
void cleanup();

// Entry point.
int main() {
  // Initialize OpenCL.
  if(!init_opencl()) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Initialize the problem data.
  // Requires the number of devices to be known.
  init_problem();

  // Run the kernel.
  run();

  // Free the resources allocated
  cleanup();

  return 0;
}

/////// HELPER FUNCTIONS ///////

// Randomly generate a floating-point number between -10 and 10.
float rand_float() {
  return float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX) * 20.0f - 10.0f;
}

// Initializes the OpenCL objects.
bool init_opencl() {
  cl_int status;

  printf("Initializing OpenCL\n");

  if(!setCwdToExeDir()) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get the OpenCL platform.
  platform = findPlatform("Altera");
  if(platform == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: Unable to find Altera OpenCL platform.\n");
    return false;
  }

  // Query the available OpenCL device.
  device.reset(getDevices(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &num_devices));
  printf("Platform: %s\n", getPlatformName(platform).c_str());
  printf("Using %d device(s)\n", num_devices);
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    printf("  %s\n", getDeviceName(device[i]).c_str());
  }

  // Create the context.
  context = clCreateContext(NULL, num_devices, device, NULL, NULL, &status);
  checkError(status, "Failed to create context");

  // Create the program for all device. Use the first device as the
  // representative device (assuming all device are of the same type).
  std::string binary_file = getBoardBinaryFile("vectorAdd", device[0]);
  printf("Using AOCX: %s\n", binary_file.c_str());
  program = createProgramFromBinary(context, binary_file.c_str(), device, num_devices);

  // Build the program that was just created.
  status = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, "", NULL, NULL);
  checkError(status, "Failed to build program");

  // Create per-device objects.
  queue.reset(num_devices);
  kernel.reset(num_devices);
  n_per_device.reset(num_devices);
  input_a_buf.reset(num_devices);
  input_b_buf.reset(num_devices);
  output_buf.reset(num_devices);

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    // Command queue.
    queue[i] = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device[i], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &status);
    checkError(status, "Failed to create command queue");

    // Kernel.
    const char *kernel_name = "vectorAdd";
    kernel[i] = clCreateKernel(program, kernel_name, &status);
    checkError(status, "Failed to create kernel");

    // Determine the number of elements processed by this device.
    n_per_device[i] = N / num_devices; // number of elements handled by this device

    // Spread out the remainder of the elements over the first
    // N % num_devices.
    if(i < (N % num_devices)) {
      n_per_device[i]++;
    }

    // Input buffers.
    input_a_buf[i] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
        n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), NULL, &status);
    checkError(status, "Failed to create buffer for input A");

    input_b_buf[i] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
        n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), NULL, &status);
    checkError(status, "Failed to create buffer for input B");

    // Output buffer.
    output_buf[i] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
        n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), NULL, &status);
    checkError(status, "Failed to create buffer for output");
  }

  return true;
}

// Initialize the data for the problem. Requires num_devices to be known.
void init_problem() {
  if(num_devices == 0) {
    checkError(-1, "No devices");
  }

  input_a.reset(num_devices);
  input_b.reset(num_devices);
  output.reset(num_devices);
  ref_output.reset(num_devices);

  // Generate input vectors A and B and the reference output consisting
  // of a total of N elements.
  // We create separate arrays for each device so that each device has an
  // aligned buffer. 
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    input_a[i].reset(n_per_device[i]);
    input_b[i].reset(n_per_device[i]);
    output[i].reset(n_per_device[i]);
    ref_output[i].reset(n_per_device[i]);

    for(unsigned j = 0; j < n_per_device[i]; ++j) {
      input_a[i][j] = rand_float();
      input_b[i][j] = rand_float();
      ref_output[i][j] = input_a[i][j] + input_b[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void run() {
  cl_int status;

  const double start_time = getCurrentTimestamp();

  // Launch the problem for each device.
  scoped_array<cl_event> kernel_event(num_devices);
  scoped_array<cl_event> finish_event(num_devices);

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {

    // Transfer inputs to each device. Each of the host buffers supplied to
    // clEnqueueWriteBuffer here is already aligned to ensure that DMA is used
    // for the host-to-device transfer.
    cl_event write_event[2];
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[i], input_a_buf[i], CL_FALSE,
        0, n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), input_a[i], 0, NULL, &write_event[0]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to transfer input A");

    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[i], input_b_buf[i], CL_FALSE,
        0, n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), input_b[i], 0, NULL, &write_event[1]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to transfer input B");

    // Set kernel arguments.
    unsigned argi = 0;

    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], argi++, sizeof(cl_mem), &input_a_buf[i]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to set argument %d", argi - 1);

    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], argi++, sizeof(cl_mem), &input_b_buf[i]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to set argument %d", argi - 1);

    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], argi++, sizeof(cl_mem), &output_buf[i]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to set argument %d", argi - 1);

    // Enqueue kernel.
    // Use a global work size corresponding to the number of elements to add
    // for this device.
    // 
    // We don't specify a local work size and let the runtime choose
    // (it'll choose to use one work-group with the same size as the global
    // work-size).
    //
    // Events are used to ensure that the kernel is not launched until
    // the writes to the input buffers have completed.
    const size_t global_work_size = n_per_device[i];
    printf("Launching for device %d (%d elements)\n", i, global_work_size);

    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[i], kernel[i], 1, NULL,
        &global_work_size, NULL, 2, write_event, &kernel_event[i]);
    checkError(status, "Failed to launch kernel");

    // Read the result. This the final operation.
    status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue[i], output_buf[i], CL_FALSE,
        0, n_per_device[i] * sizeof(float), output[i], 1, &kernel_event[i], &finish_event[i]);

    // Release local events.
    clReleaseEvent(write_event[0]);
    clReleaseEvent(write_event[1]);
  }

  // Wait for all devices to finish.
  clWaitForEvents(num_devices, finish_event);

  const double end_time = getCurrentTimestamp();

  // Wall-clock time taken.
  printf("\nTime: %0.3f ms\n", (end_time - start_time) * 1e3);

  // Get kernel times using the OpenCL event profiling API.
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    cl_ulong time_ns = getStartEndTime(kernel_event[i]);
    printf("Kernel time (device %d): %0.3f ms\n", i, double(time_ns) * 1e-6);
  }

  // Release all events.
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    clReleaseEvent(kernel_event[i]);
    clReleaseEvent(finish_event[i]);
  }

  // Verify results.
  bool pass = true;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices && pass; ++i) {
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < n_per_device[i] && pass; ++j) {
      if(fabsf(output[i][j] - ref_output[i][j]) > 1.0e-5f) {
        printf("Failed verification @ device %d, index %d\nOutput: %f\nReference: %f\n",
            i, j, output[i][j], ref_output[i][j]);
        pass = false;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\nVerification: %s\n", pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
}

// Free the resources allocated during initialization
void cleanup() {
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i) {
    if(kernel && kernel[i]) {
      clReleaseKernel(kernel[i]);
    }
    if(queue && queue[i]) {
      clReleaseCommandQueue(queue[i]);
    }
    if(input_a_buf && input_a_buf[i]) {
      clReleaseMemObject(input_a_buf[i]);
    }
    if(input_b_buf && input_b_buf[i]) {
      clReleaseMemObject(input_b_buf[i]);
    }
    if(output_buf && output_buf[i]) {
      clReleaseMemObject(output_buf[i]);
    }
  }

  if(program) {
    clReleaseProgram(program);
  }
  if(context) {
    clReleaseContext(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few sub-questions here, so let me try and address them individually. I'm going to be slightly pedantic on terminology; I'm not doing that to be snarky but hopefully this will help you make more sense of documentation, examples, etc.:

> Would it be correct to say: each kernel uses 1 element from A and 1 element from B to calculate 1 element of Z?

The *kernel* is just the code that will run on the OpenCL device. Typically, a kernel is scheduled to run (using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`) with multiple *work-items*. With just one work item, there is not much point in bothering with OpenCL at all; the performance benefit comes from massive parallelism. In any case, your quoted statement is correct for *each individual work-item processing this kernel*. If you run this kernel with 1000 work items, 1000 elements from A will be processed with 1000 elements from B to calculate 1000 elements of Z. The order this happens in is deliberately undefined, and at least groups of elements will be operated on concurrently.

> To me, it looks like it determines the number of devices (num_devices), and essentially divides the problem size (N) by num_devices, to determine the number of elements per device (n_per_device[]). Then it creates arrays of random numbers for each device (input_a[] and input_b[]) with n_per_device number of elements.

Yes, it looks like that to me too.

> For example, say if the number of devices available is 1000,

I would just like to point out that you will pretty much *never* have this many OpenCL devices in a system. The granularity of a single OpenCL device is typically "one GPU," or "all the CPU cores in the system," or "one FPGA accelerator card."

So a "normal" amount of devices on a desktop system is 1, 2, or maybe up to about 4 (e.g. CPU + iGPU + dual discrete GPUs). Big irons with many accelerator cards might have ~16 or so. If you're attempting to accelerate some code in a desktop (or small server) application, you'll usually just pick one device that's likely to be the most appropriate for your problem and run with that. Distributing workload evenly across heterogenous devices is a hard problem for anything but the most basic algorithms.

> and problem size (N) is 1,000,000; the n_per_device is 1000 (and since there is no remainder it is the same for all), and it would generate 1000 arrays of input_a and input_b, with 1000 elements in each. Then a respective pair of arrays of 1000 elements are taken by the kernel and added together -

Yes.

> in other words each execution of the kernel adds 1000 elements?

Again, this is where using the term "kernel" isn't precise enough. In your example, you would enqueue 1000 *work items* to execute the kernel on each of the 1000 devices.